# openCV triangulatePoints acting strange in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to calculate the 3D points using OpenCV to being a multiple view reconstruction. I perform the standard sequences of finding matching points using SIFT, then getting the Fundamental and Essential Matrix with a known camera calibration matrix. After recovering the pose of the second cam relative to the first, I go on to try and triangulate the points. All other parts of the code work well and as expected. But this one part gets glitchy. I am using OpenCV 4.3.0. Sometimes triangulatePoints just breaks the IDE (Spyder), sometimes it gives me the points, and sometimes it gives me a bunch of points at [1,1,1]. The IDE also breaks if the number of points is over 200. The more points the more glitchy it seems to get.
This is getting frustrating, any help would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
F, mask = cv.findFundamentalMat(pts1,pts2,cv.FM_LMEDS)
# We select only inlier points
pts1 = pts1[mask.ravel()==1]
pts2 = pts2[mask.ravel()==1]

print(len(pts1),len(pts2))
print(cv.__version__)

E, mask_2 = cv.findEssentialMat(pts1, pts2, focal=f_x, pp=(O_x, O_y), method=cv.FM_LMEDS, prob=0.999, threshold=3.0)
print("Essential Matrix")
print(E)
print(" ")
points, R_1, t_1, mask_2 = cv.recoverPose(E, pts1, pts2,pts2,focal=f_x, pp=(O_x, O_y), mask = mask_2)
print("Rotation Matrix")
print(R_1)
print(" ")
R_M = R.from_matrix(R_1)
R_1_E = R_M.as_euler('zyx', degrees=True)
print("angles (z,y,x) or (alpha, beta, gamma) Z is dir of Principal Ray, Y is Vert and X is horiz")
print(R_1_E)
print("Translation")
print(t_1)

K = np.array([[f_x, 0,O_x],
             [0,f_x, O_y],
             [0,0,1]])

Pr_1 = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]])
Pr_2 = np.hstack((np.dot(K,R_1),np.dot(K,t_1)))
#Pr_2 = np.hstack((R_1,t_1))

pts1_t = pts1[:200].T
pts2_t = pts2[:200].T
#print(pts1_t)

points4D = cv.triangulatePoints(Pr_1,Pr_2,pts1_t, pts2_t)
#print(points4D.T[:3].T)
coordinate_eucl= cv.convertPointsFromHomogeneous(points4D.T)
coordinate_eucl=coordinate_eucl.reshape(-1,3)
px,py,pz=coordinate_eucl.T
coordP = []
for i in range(len(px)):
    coordP.append([px[i],py[i],pz[i]])
print(coordP[:20])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the triangulate points function in OpenCV Python does not work very well.

I used the functions created by Eliasvan, here:
https://github.com/Eliasvan/Multiple-Quadrotor-SLAM/blob/master/Work/python_libs/triangulation.py

I used the Linear_LS_Triangulation Function, worked very well for me, and fast.